# Laravel Verification Link With Session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-session

I need to redirect back with a message.

> Active link sent successfully.

```php
<a href="{{ route('verification.resend') }}">request another</a>
```

How do I create a session to link if I'm not using any form?

Comment: This information is not enough to understand. Please elaborate your question with more detail. How you have tried with controller and which controller handle this link.

Comment: i did't Do anything in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check how Laravel handles this feature in `VerifiesEmail::resend()`

```
/**
 * Resend the email verification notification.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function resend(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return back()->with('resent', true);
}
```

You will also notice that on a successful action, it is returning back with a `resent` key in your session.

So, in your blade file you could just do this.

```
@if (Session::has('resent'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">Your activation link has been sent successfully</div>
@endif
```